# Can I give myself multiple turns at once with Beacon's of Tomorrows?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If somehow I cast multiple copies of [Beacon of Tomorrows](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeacon%20of%20Tomorrows%5d) at once or in the same turn, will I get all of the turns back to back? Or, because of it's wording, would all of the extra turns happen in the exact same point of time?

Comment: You might find the previous discussion on Lighthouse Chronologist illuminating.  https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9492/if-there-are-two-lighthouse-chronologist-with-three-players-will-one-player-be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get it back to back. See [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020180119.pdf).

> 500.7. Some effects can give a player extra turns. They do this by adding the turns directly after the specified turn. **If a player is
>   given multiple extra turns, the extra turns are added one at a time.**
>   If multiple players are given extra turns, the extra turns are added
>   one at a time, in APNAP order (see rule 101.4). The most recently
>   created turn will be taken first.